# what is the verb for water going past a rock?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, terminology, is-it-a-word

I'm looking for a verb to describe the "Y" thing the water makes when it hits a rock, for example in the river. Here is a professional piece of art I made (view from the top): [image]

Is it simply called "going around"? Or there's/re another word/s for it?

Here's the sentence example: "He stood in the middle of the shallow river, the water _____ him."

Comment: Please can you supply an example sentence you would use the word in?

Comment: If you want technical language, as your picture suggests maybe you do, you could try Physics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Y" shape of the water is caused by the water "**splitting**" around the obstacle. Another word would be "**bifurcate**" which means splitting into two paths (such as bifurcation of the water flow), but that may be too technical sounding. If that is the case, the path of the water is certainly "**parting**".  Or, less directly, one could simply state that the stream "**surrounded**" him (*diverging* around him naturally - thus splitting is implied).

"He stood in the middle of the shallow river, the water ***splitting*** around him."

"He stood in the middle of the shallow river, the water ***bifurcating*** around him."

"He stood in the middle of the shallow river, the water ***parting*** about him."

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/split

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bifurcate

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/part

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/surround

Comment: Bifurcate is probably the most accurate description, though it's too technical/formal-sounding.

Comment: Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anabranch

Comment: Parting, definitely

Comment: Why not just *fork*?

Answer (score 2):

If flowed is unacceptable then how about "curved around", or even "slid past/by". For a bit of color, "rushed by".

Answer (score 0):

I would say "the water **rippled** past the rock".

[image]
[image]

Comment: please elaborate

Answer (score -1):

***To bend:***

"(Of a road, river, or path)

deviate from a straight line in a specified direction."
(https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bend)

Here's an example from Reverso.context.net:

It's like water ***bending*** around a rock in a stream, and all that light just destroys the shadow.